# does $\|3x\|^2 = 3\|x\|^2$

Tags: normed-spaces

Does the norm squared follow the same properties as the norm? If the question was does ||3x|| = 3||x|| then I know I can do it, but what does the square change. Would the answer instead be $\|3x\|^2 = 9\|x\|^2?$

Comment: Have you tried an example?

Comment: Of $a=3b$ then $a^2=(3b)^2=9b^2.$

Comment: If you know that $\|3x\| = 3\|x\|$, then square both sides and...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the square affects things and you are correct that $\|3x\|^2=9\|x\|^2$.  In general we have that $\|\alpha x\|^n = |\alpha|^n\cdot\|x\|^n$

To see this, recall that $\|\alpha x\| = |\alpha|\cdot \|x\|$ is one of the defining properties of a norm.  We have then $\|\alpha x\|^n = (|\alpha|\cdot \|x\|)^n = |\alpha|^n\cdot \|x\|^n$ by properties of exponentiation and multiplication.